# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in NSCoder

Tags: ios, swift3

I am getting nil error at `isSelected(Bool)`.  Please check below screenshot for more detail.

[image]

import Foundation

```
class StatusEntity: `NSObject`, `NSCoding` {

    var Value: String
    var Native_Description: String
    var isSelected: Bool

    override init() {
        Value = ""
        Native_Description = ""
        isSelected = false
    }

    @objc required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        Value = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "Value") as! String
        Native_Description = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "Native_Description") as! String
        isSelected = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "isSelected") as! Bool
    }

    @objc func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(Value, forKey: "Value")
        aCoder.encode(Native_Description, forKey: "Native_Description")
        aCoder.encode(isSelected, forKey: "isSelected")
    }
}
```

This is the `CollectionView` Code

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell: StatusCheckCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "statusCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! StatusCheckCollectionViewCell

        let entity: StatusEntity = arrayList[indexPath.item]
        cell.txtName.text = entity.Native_Description

        // Making CollectionView Cell Right Align
        var scalingTransform : CGAffineTransform!
        scalingTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1);
        cell.transform = scalingTransform
        cell.btnItem.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.btnItem.addTarget(self, action: #selector(StatusTableViewCell.onItemClicker(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

        if(entity.isSelected){
            cell.imgCheckBox.image = UIImage(named: "CheckBoxSelected")
        } else {
            cell.imgCheckBox.image = UIImage(named: "CheckBox")
        }
        return cell
    }

    func onItemClicker(_ sender: UIButton){
        let entity: StatusEntity = arrayList[sender.tag]
        entity.isSelected = !entity.isSelected
        let indexPath: IndexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
        collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])

        // Saving values to DB
        var submitEntity: SubmitDocumentEntity = SubmitDocumentEntity()
        let insertEntity = dataStorage.getSubmitDocumentEntity()
        if(!insertEntity.isKind(of: NSNull.self)){
            submitEntity = dataStorage.getSubmitDocumentEntity() as! SubmitDocumentEntity
        }
        if(entity.isSelected) {
            if(!submitEntity.TransactionTypes.contains(entity.Value)){
                submitEntity.TransactionTypes.append(entity.Value)
            }
        } else {
            if(submitEntity.TransactionTypes.contains(entity.Value)){
                let index = submitEntity.TransactionTypes.index(of: entity.Value)
                submitEntity.TransactionTypes.remove(at: index!)
            }
        }
        dataStorage.putSubmitDocumentEntity(submitEntity)
    }
}
```

Comment: @vadian thanks for update and answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to decode an **object**. In terms of `NSCoding` a `Bool` is **not** an object.

There are dedicated methods for *primitive* types.

```
isSelected = aDecoder.decodeBool(forKey: "isSelected")
```

Ad please conform to the naming convention that variable names start with a lowercase letter and are *camelCased* rather than *snake_cased*